# How To Display Variable Value In View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

Here I am trying to display variable `y` value in `td` in view(i.e .cshtml).
But have no idea how to do that.

Below is my view:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.District)
</td>
<td>
    @{
        var y = v.GetContestantAverageRatingByContestantId(item.ContestantId);
    }
</td>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways. For example simply using `@` like this:

```
<td>
    @y
</td>
```

Or by using a `<span>` tag like this:

```
<span>Your Text @(y) ...</span>
```

Or using `Html.Label` helper:

```
@Html.Label("lblName", y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Razor’s `@`. Try this code:

```
@{
    var y = v.GetContestantAverageRatingByContestantId(item.ContestantId);
}
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.District)
</td>
<td>
    @y
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.District)
</td>
<td>
     @Html.Raw(v.GetContestantAverageRatingByContestantId(item.ContestantId))
</td>
```